# Decreasing Font Size When Width Overflows Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I believe my question is unique because I am using a counter whose width can constantly increase, as opposed to the container width changing, which is what seems to usually be asked.

My site is http://script-timer.com/, and I am trying to decrease the font of the timer when it overflows its container div. Here is the javascript I am currently working on to accomplish this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    while( $('#scriptTime').width() > $('#timer-container').width() ) {
        $('#scriptTime').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#scriptTime').css('font-size')) - 1) + "rem" );
    } 
});
```

This looks like right to me, but being as I am very much still learning, I am most likely missing something simple. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can create a responsive font size by using v units. Try doing `font-size:2vh;` or something like that. Resize the window and notice as the size changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: I have tried playing around with Viewport Percentage Units, but it does not seem to scale if the font itself is resizing - such as when the timer interval increases to over a minute. At that point, the font is just overflowing the container.

Comment: Consider using css !! Have a look at this article - https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: I will look over the articles on viewport sized typography again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the plugin: https://plugins.jquery.com/textfill/
And a link to the source: http://jquery-textfill.github.io/

or

add this in css method

overflow: auto;

Comment: Took some fiddling, but that was just what I needed - thank you kind sir!